# ASP.NET project crashing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Community, and I have an ASP.NET project that I have edited before on this machine that now has started to crash Visual Studio every time I try to open the solution.

I have tried the following:

> devenv.exe /resetusersettings
>
> devenv.exe /resetsettings
>
> devenv.exe /safemode
>
> devenv.exe /log
>
> Disable third-party addons
>
> Repair installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community
>
> Create new project and add files manually

None of the above have managed to solve the issue. The new project crashes Visual Studio as soon as I try to add a page to the project. When I debug, the exception is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll

[image: exception]

I have also tried to disable code analysis by running a Developer Command Prompt and executing the following: `set DevDivCodeAnalysisRunType=Disabled`, `devenv.exe` and still experienced the crash.

My Visual Studio installation is up to date. The only thing I have not tried is complete uninstall/reinstall. Everything works fine in a separate Windows Forms project. And as mentioned above, this same project was working previously with no changes made in between.

**EDIT**

After running `fuslogvw.exe` I see a log of failed bindings, looking like so:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/14/2016 @ 12:19:08 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This is an inspection only bind.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity/Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Some of the earlier logs I had been looking at seemed to indicate other binding failures, so I tried removing VisualSVN completely, and still getting the crash. I think I will have to try a complete uninstall/reinstall of Visual Studio, since previous repair install attempts were unsuccessful.

Comment: This is usually a platform problem. Is your build configuration set to Any CPU? x64? x86?

Comment: Maybe try editing the .sln file in Notepad and looking for wonky stuff you don't recognize? Maybe try removing the *.sln.suo files inside the root directory of the solution, including any *.csproj.user files you might have. Those are specific to your computer, and maybe one of them got corrupted? Maybe try editing the .sln file using the Visual Studio Binary editor. Invisible or strange characters can play havoc if an application isn't written to handle it.

Comment: Ah, I should also add that I have deleted the `.suo` files, as well as the files in the `.vs` directory.

Comment: @Crowcoder looks like it is currently set to `Any CPU`..

Comment: @Crowcoder same results trying `x86` and `x64` in the empty project. Crashes as soon as I add an `.aspx` page with code-behind.

Comment: then you will have to investigate assembly loading failures. There is a tool called [fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) for doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the tool @Crowcoder, looks like an issue with VisualSVN. Seeing this in some failed bindings: `LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN/bin/en/VisualSVN.UI.resources.EXE`... I'm not seeing a `en` or `en-us` subfolder in the `bin` folder.